# Vector input from user - python

Tags: python, vector

I am trying to get a vector using the input function to do the mathematical operation. Below is the code I am using.

Any pointers will help

Thanks,
Prashant

```
vector1=input()

(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)

vector1=np.array(vectors.split(','),dtype=np.int16)


Error:
line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-109-6cf21e5e043d>", line 1, in <module>
    vector1=np.array(vectors.split(','),dtype=np.int16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "('(1"
```

Comment: You're splitting the commas but not the parentheses. They're still there (shown by the error).

Comment: Thanks TrebuchetMS but still it doesn't resolve completely when i converting to array (it is of datatype -dtype='<U23') but I want it to be int dtype

Comment: Is your goal to create a 1-dimensional numpy array or to create a 2-dimensional (3-by-3) numpy array?

Comment: goal is to create (3 by 3 ) numpy array

Answer (score 1):

With a little help of [regular expressions](https://regex101.com/r/4MU3pP/1) you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import re

user_input = "(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)"

# Convert user-provided string to nested list
x = re.findall(r"\((\d+(?:,\d+)*)\)", user_input)
x = [part.split(',') for part in x]

# Create 2D numpy array from nested list
arr = np.array(x, dtype=int)

print(arr)
# Output:
# [[1 2 3]
#  [4 5 6]
#  [7 8 9]]
```

Comment: @PrashantNayak You're welcome. If this answer was useful, then please [upvote it and/or mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).